# What Problems are the UN facing and what Reforms will be needed to boost UN's efficiency?

Tags: united-nations, history

I have been watching the recent 75th General Debate and I have seen some presidents ([Ghanaian President](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9ezHsVMSuU)...)  urging and proclaiming for UN Reforms to boost UN efficiency on dealing with problems but also UN Reforms to modernize the old UN system. My Question would be what's wrong with the UN, why is there a need for reform and what reforms are needed and what is the plans of reforming UN? Additionally, why is the system not compatible with today's world as many are speaking of modernization?

Comment: Reforms? What reforms are they asking for?

Comment: That's part of the Question.

Comment: I see you mention reforms but nothing about what types of reforms.

Comment: Are the reforms something that will allow them to respond to a crisis sooner?

Answer (score 4):

The most prominent point of critique is the Security Council. As outlined in the answer above, its setup resembles the power balance after WWII. Therefore, key issues, nowadays are:

1. Enlargement, possibly based on regional representation (meaning a number of countries per continent);
2. Abolition of, or extension of veto power, and its use;
3. Changing the system of permanent and non-permanent categories of membership;
4. Generally the wokring process.
   Source: https://www.un.org/pga/74/2020/02/13/security-council-reform-2/

Japan, Brazil, Germany and India are especially hard on pushing for SC reform as they aspire to become permanent members of it https://english.kyodonews.net/news/2020/09/ffa7443a9ab5-japan-brazil-germany-india-call-for-un-security-council-reform.html

Comment: Abolition of veto power sounds a little bit unreasonable. None of the 5 permanent security council members would approve it. It might be useful, but it’s most likely never going to happen. Unless somebody manages to pull some legal jumbo.

Comment: Abolition of veto powers is rather unrealistic, that is correct. Reforming the concept in the direction of extending it to other UN member states (e.g. more permanent members or replace the seat of France with a common EU seat), or changing the rules about their use are is more likely

Answer (score 3):

**The UN was *designed* to prevent another World War.**

It represented the post-war order, with the US, UK and USSR (the major victors) getting permanent Security Council seats and France and China (the minor victors) getting two more. When the five veto powers agreed on something, and they got a few of the non-permanent members to go along, that was pretty much the consensus world opinion. The General Assembly, by contrast, was allowed to meet and debate and pass powerless resolutions.

So the superpowers had a forum to meet and debate. Sometimes it helped.

**A more powerful UN is not in the interest of *powerful* nations.**

And arguably a more democratic UN isn't in their interests, either. Why should the five permanent members agree to a dilution of their powers? And why should autocracies want any oversight? I can see four kinds of complaints:

- Powerful nations complaining that things are not going as they wish *all* the time. That's mostly along the lines of "*we* use our veto responsibly, *they* are obstructive." Yeah, sure.
- Idealists complaining that the UN isn't organized on a democratic principle of "one person, one vote."
- Moderately powerful nations complaining that they pay [relatively high contributions](https://betterworldcampaign.org/us-un-partnership/un-budget-formula/) for relatively little power.
- Various nations complaining that the checks and balances create gridlock and inefficiency.

Few people want a world government at this time, not even a democratic one.

Comment: I don't think that this applies to just the more powerful countries as I don't think it is a stretch to say that many authoritarian countries also don't want the UN to have more power and be able to interfere with them

Comment: @JoeW, wouldn't those nations want the UN as it is now? The OP asked about reforms.

Comment: I mentioned that in response to the remarks about powerful nations not wanting the UN to have more power. There are weaker countries that also don't want it to have more power so that it can't interfere with them.

Comment: @JoeW, I added a sentence to that effect.

Comment: I don't think the call for reform is to make the UN a "world government" but a more open, leveled, platform for everybody to meet and discuss. Also, by itself alone, does the UN has the execution power?

Comment: @r13, the UNSC can authorize member nations to use military force other than in self-defense.

Comment: @o.m. The "veto" power and the conflicts between the UNSC members made the UN to use military means almost impossible unless we found the "Aggressive Aliens". :)

Comment: @r13, you asked about powers of the UN and I replied what it can do. Talking about the UN "alone," without any members in support, is a bit pointless. It is no country.

Comment: @o.m. "It is no country" is my point - "I don't think the call for reform is to make the UN a world government", which is a direct response to your closing comment - "Few people want a world government at this time, ..." It simply can't be one (in reality).

Comment: @r13, I think that it **could** be a world government if enough states wanted that. Look at the EU, which has been loaned the exercise of sovereign powers by sovereign states.